# Inspect a Flux stream by an operator

Tags: java, project-reactor

I try to inspect an existing stream but couldn't find a special operator so far.

```
Flux.just(1, 2, 3)
    // just inspect every element
    .map(e -> {
        System.out.println(e);
        return e;
    })
    .subscribe();
```

I'm looking for an operator like [`peek()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) of Java Streams or [`tap()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) in RxJS.

Comment: Seems it `take()`, or `all()` operatoins can help

Comment: Seems that `doOnNext(System.out::println)` works as desired. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you comment, `doOnNext(System.out::println)` will just print every element, which may be enough for simple use cases. (In general, `doOnNext()` is used for side effects, so equivalent to `tap()` in that sense.)

However, if debugging is your primary purpose, you may also want to look at `log()`, which gives you more information that could be useful (such as notifying you of subscriptions, requests, etc. as well as each element, and how they tie together.) For example:

```
Flux.just(1, 2, 3)
        .log()
        .subscribe();
```

Prints:

```
[ INFO] (main) | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] FluxArray.ArraySubscription)
[ INFO] (main) | request(unbounded)
[ INFO] (main) | onNext(1)
[ INFO] (main) | onNext(2)
[ INFO] (main) | onNext(3)
[ INFO] (main) | onComplete()
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. It's so simple when you know the solution.